# basic animation issue - can't find animate method

Tags: android, animation

I'm reading up on Android property animation and getting stuck on the ground floor.  I have an ImageView (and a TextView) that I am trying to animate but there appears to be no "animate" method.  I type myImageView. and there are many methods that dropdown but no animate method.

I'm using Java in Eclipse and I have see other code examples where it works.
This is my ImageView...

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/molePic"
    android:layout_width="36dip"
    android:layout_height="36dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:src="@drawable/mutebeacon36x36" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`View.animate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#animate()) method was added in API level 12 ([Android 3.1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)).  What version of Android are you compiling against?

Comment: That's it.  I compiled at 15 and it is there.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is an example animation method. it will translate a view 500 pixels to the right in 1000 millisecs.

```
public void startMyAnimation(final View view) {

    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 500, 0, 0);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    view.startAnimation(animation);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            isAnimating = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

         }
    });
}
```

and you call it like so

```
startMyAnimation(findViewById(R.id.molePic));
```